# Removing Research from Office 2007 installs

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

Is there any way to disable the "Research" feature (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd>) in Microsoft Office 2007?  It would be better if there was a policy setting or install option that I've missed, but if not, can you disable it post-install?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this a problem?

Comment: Because it locks up the program while it loads the research pane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/win2003/t1152549969), you can't disable the Research pane but you can speed it up by clicking the "Research Options" button and then clicking "Update/Remove" to remove all the online searches.

Comment: That does make a major difference, it will be a pity if you can't remove it, but this is better than nothing

Answer (score 1):

This works in Word and Excel, and I assume it will work in Outlook. To disable the Research task pane:

From the Office application, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> to open the VB Editor.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to open the Immediate Window.

Type this line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
Application.CommandBars("Research").Enabled = False
```

Answer (score 1):

Press alt click that will enable the options on the down arrow sign besides the research title window Choose close.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is it just went away after killing it a bunch of times. I have seen some very happy people on annoyance.org saying:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + click the <kbd>X</kbd> to close.